# Button Click To Call First Viewcontroller To Another Viewcontroller Method Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have multiple `UIViewController` objects within one main `UIViewController`. I need to call `FVC` method when I click the main view controller button. Here three view controllers having three separate class files.

[image]

Comment: What you want to do after JSON work?

Comment: Put your code what you have done >

Answer (score 0):

From your `first controller` on `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` method,

```
    UIStoryboard * board = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController * cntrl = [board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:cntrl animated:YES completion:^{

    }];
```

add above code. Here `ViewController` is nothing but a your `Second view controller`. Using reference of `cntrl` pass data to `Second controller`.
When you want to navigate to any other controller without having `navigation controller` reference , you use `present view controller`.

Comment: NO. I dont want navigate. Btw I need to call second viewcontroller class methode but app should stay first viewcontroller. Its like background process.@Bharath

Comment: What you want to do by calling a method in Second view controller. As your question says you want to do some JSON data parsing etc... Your requirement is not correct. If you want to do any such of things like doing JSON parsing, create a new class with subclassing NSObject and then write your code in that. You shouldn't call other controller methods to achieve this functionality.

Comment: @ Bharath Vankireddy - I have update my question buddy cool and look once!

Comment: Small Question, how did you add 2 controllers in one controller ? Is that possible in iOS ?

Comment: Yes we can add into pageviewcontroller. Page viewcontroller to multiple viewcontroller we can add! @Bharath Vankireddy

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call a method present in other ViewController without presenting it, I guess you are doing it wrong, because that method belongs that ViewController class and ideally should be called when that ViewController's lifecycle is in progress.

For your scenario, I suggest that you should create a utility class, move that method which accepts two strings and then processes something in that utility class and then call that method from your ViewController1 something like :

`[UtilityClassName yourMethodWithFirstString : str1 andSecondString : str2];`

Hope that clears.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewController *viewVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:viewVC animated:YES completion:nil];

//Loading a view controller from the storyboard
UIViewController *viewVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_OF_YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER"];
[self presentViewController:viewVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: this is not I expected!

Answer (score 0):

```
In First View Controller
//Do this inside your btnCall method
SecondViewController * cntrl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewControllerIdentifier"];
[cntrl methodName:firstParameter:secondParameter];

In SecondViewController

In .h file
-(void)methodName:firstParameter:secondParameter;

In .m file
-(void)methodName:firstParameter:secondParameter{
//Do your task here
}
```

Comment: Give detaily. I this is I need!@xphobia

Comment: create a method in second view controller like

-(void) methodName:first parameter:secondParameter

and call in first view controller with two parametes

Comment: [cntrl methodName:firstParameter:secondParameter]; I am not clear give me detaily please @xphobia

Comment: No visible @Interface for firstviewcontroller declares the selector 'methodeName::' error showing

Comment: Declare the method in .h file of secondViewController and then define it in .m file , then this error will not come